# Custom appearance for KendoTabstrip

Tags: c#, css, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

Can tabs in Kendo tabstrip be custom designed???

I need to add arrow shaped tabs(Like the image added) instead of the regular rectangular ones.

[image: Arrow shaped Tabs]
How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to overwrite the css for kendo element: .k-item and .k-state-default

You can add border-right or use background-image css syntax.